# The meaning of complete variety as alternative definition of (traditional) compactness

Tags: algebraic-geometry

According to the following [PDF](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014-c7.pdf) on page 62,

*"every prevariety is compact in the Zariski topology, and
so in particular that compactness in the Zariski topology does not capture the same geometric idea
as in the classical case. We therefore need an **alternative** description of the intuitive compactness
property that works in our algebraic setting of the Zariski topology."*

When reading the above text, I understand it  as

'the classical definition of compactness is not useful/meaningful concept to distinguish any prevariety $X$( because whenever any prevariety $X$ is given, $X$ is compact). Though, one wants to design the ***alternative*** definition of compactness based on the basic property that compactness is preserved by any continuous mapping.

Thus, I can understand the background of definition of closed map ( **Definition 7.17** on the PDF) and the complete variety ( **Definition 7.21** on the PDF). thus,  like [a description of the complete variety on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_variety), the idea of complete variety can be seen as an analogue of compactness in algebraic geometry. But **I cannot understand the precise meaning that a variety is complete or not complete**

For example, a projective variety , $\mathbb{P}^n $ ,and an affine variety $\mathbb{A}^n$  is compact because both are prevariety. However, the former is complete where as the latter is **not** complete. but as I said(or according to the Wikipedia text), complete variety is analogue of compactness. Thus my understanding is

> "the former is something like compact object whereas the latter is
> something like not compact object". ....... (★)

But, I cannot imagine  the sentence (★)
, why the former should see as a compact-like structure, and the latter is non-compact-like structure, even though both are compactness in the sense of traditional definition of compactness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Intuition**

When people say completeness (or properness) is analogous to compactness, they are really comparing different topologies: completeness/properness in Zariski topology is analogous to compactness in "usual analytic topology". One way to formalize this statement is via GAGA, e.g. theorem 21 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Echd/expo/GAGA.pdf).

So from an intuitive level, $\mathbb{P}^n$ is complete "because" over $\mathbb{C}$, you know that $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact in usual topology. Whereas $\mathbb{A}^n$ is not complete "because" over $\mathbb{C}$, you know that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not compact in usual topology.

**Proofs**
If you are actually looking for proofs why $\mathbb{P}^n$ is complete/proper while $\mathbb{A}^n$ isn't,

- this [old blogpost](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/a-projective-morphism-is-proper/) shows that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is complete; similar proof likely exists in standard texts (Hartshorne etc) as well.
- this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125740/why-is-a-proper-affine-morphism-finite) shows that proper, affine map must be finite, and so $\mathbb{A}^n$ is not complete as long as $n > 0$.